# Parsing '\n' to '\n ctrl-l' with Python

Tags: python, linux, parsing

I have a program that can access Python from inside within it's initial file, that looks like

> #initial file
>   source py_commands.py
>   py_cmd

I want to grep from inside that program `\n` and parse it to `\n ctrl-l`.
Ctrl-l is just a combined key stroke like in bash, screen or other TUI and invokes a command in this program, which I otherwise always have manually to type and should only be invoked after a `\n`.

I tried this without success:

```
x = raw_input()
print(x + '\u000C')
```

I'm not well versed in Python and only need this one piece.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input()` strips the trailing newline. If you want the string to end with `\n` `\f` (Ctrl-L is *Form Feed*), you have to add both.

```
x = raw_input()
print(x+'\n\f')
```